# Numpy polynomial division in rings

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, python-3.8

Is it possible to divide polynomials in rings of 2 for example (which includes only 0 and 1 elements) with numpy or I need to write special func for it? In my task I need to get reminder of division in ring of two (Z2)

I tried to use numpy polydiv but it doesn't work with special narrow rings like Z2 so I get wrong result sometimes when it includes negative numbers
Is there some ways to solve this problem in numpy?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IiJ9.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTPtv.png)

Comment: Please do not use screenshots in questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [galois](https://mhostetter.github.io/galois/latest/) for this.
Example:

```
import galois

# define the field with 2 elements
GF = galois.GF(2)

# define two polynomials:
p = galois.Poly([1, 0, 1, 1], field=GF)
q = galois.Poly([1, 1], field=GF)

print(f"{p = }\n{q = }")
```

It gives:

```
p = Poly(x^3 + x + 1, GF(2))
q = Poly(x + 1, GF(2))
```

Quotient and reminder:

```
print(f"{p // q = }\n{p % q = }")
```

It gives:

```
p // q = Poly(x^2 + x, GF(2))
p % q = Poly(1, GF(2))
```